# php convert date value preferred to mysql date

Tags: php, mysql

I have get data from oracle database and date value kept on 27-MAY-09. I need to insert this value to mysql database via PHP. I need to convert date format as 2009-05-27.

Any one know about it please let me know correct php statement for do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `date()` function

```
$date = '27-MAY-09';
$newData = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

[php fiddle](http://codepad.org/76ieVHHX)

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-y', $inputDate);
$newDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

PHP 5.3 not earlier.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$date1 = "27-MAY-09";
$data2 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date1));
```